# WSO2 4.9.0 line break issues parsing JSON when running as a service (YAJSW)

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, yajsw, wso2-esb

Using WSO2 ESB (4.9) to feed our dot net app with JSON formatted API calls, I'm getting errors whenever line breaks are present in the source data, but only when running the ESB as a service (via YAJSW).
The line breaks come from a database as char(10)'s and are encoded by the ESB in combination with WSO2 DSS on their way through to a simple PUT call.

The issues at the API end display in the following ways:

```
Unable to translate bytes [A0] at index 332 from specified code page to Unicode
```

Or

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: R.
```

Removing all line breaks from the source works regardless of whether running the ESB in console (admin) or as a service.
Running WSO2 ESB from an admin console also resolves the issue (but won't work long term as this needs to run automatically on the machine).

Questions are:

- Why would behaviour or WSO2's ESB change when running under the java service wrapper?
- Are there any suggestions for a fix?